# Updating control from a child thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I'm trying to update a button control from a child thread. 
I get some problems with passing parameters to the new thread.
I get the following message:
No overload for 'UpdateText' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart' (CS0123)

As far as I understand ParameterizedThreadStart takes and type "object" argument. How can I cast the object "button1" to Button in my UpdateText method?

```
    public delegate void MyDelegate(Control ctrl);
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thr =new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(UpdateText));
        thr.Start(button1);
    }

    public static void UpdateText(Control control_button)
    {
        if (control_button.InvokeRequired)
        {
            MyDelegate md = new MyDelegate(UpdateText);
            control_button.Invoke(md, control_button);
        }
        else
        {
                control_button.Text = "Updated";
        }
    }
```

Comment: you could use a lamda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change UpdateText argument to Object:

```
 public static void UpdateText(Object o)
    {
        Control control_button = (Control) o;
        // ... the rest of your code ...
```

Check this reference on [ParametrizedThreadStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Also at this line, i don't really understand what you're trying:

```
MyDelegate md = new MyDelegate(UpdateText);
control_button.Invoke(md, control_button);
```

Did you mean to:

```
 control_button.Invoke( () => {
     control_button.Text = "Updated"; 
 });
```

or

```
control_button.Invoke(MyDelegate, control_button);
```

Comment: Thanks. "Control control_button = (Control) o;" solved the problem.

I've made an instance of MyDelegate and pass to Invoke.
It seems to work pretty good.